# $P_{ij}=0$ if state $i$ is recurrent and it does not communicate with $j$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

> Suppose $P$ is the transition matrix of an infinite Markov chain. Show that if state $i$ is recurrent and it does not communicate with $j$ then $P_{ij}=0$.

I try to use the contradiction by assuming the $P_{ij}>0$. But it does not seem to work.

I get
$$P_{ij}^{k+n}\geq P_{ij}^{k}P_{ii}^{n}$$
and
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P_{ij}^{k+n}\geq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P_{ij}^{k}P_{ii}^{n}=P_{ij}^{k}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P_{ii}^{n}=\infty$$
by the recurrence of $i$.

How to get the $P_{ji}>0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessarily true that $P_{ji}>0$ under your assumptions. Indeed, consider a three state Markov chain with $P_{12}=P_{23}=P_{31}=1$ and $i=1$ and $j=2$. All states are recurrent and $P_{12}>0$ but $P_{21}=0$.

Instead, what needs to be shown is that if $P_{ij}>0$ and $i$ is recurrent, then there exists some sequence of states from $j$ back to $i$ which have positive transition probabilities. But this is clear, since if such a sequence didn't exist then once the Markov chain reached $i$ it could transition to $j$ and never reach $i$ again, contradicting recurrence of $i$.

Comment: but for all $k$, we have $P_{ji}^k=0$.

Comment: How to describe your last sentence in formula?

Comment: If for all sequences of states $x_0=j,x_1,\ldots,x_m=i$ we have $P_{x_\ell,x_{\ell+1}}=0$ then $P_{ji}^k=0$ for all $k$.

Comment: So how to show that $P_{ii}=0$?  Is it $P_{ii}=P_{ij}P_{ji}$?

Comment: No, that's obviously not true. And I'm not sure why you are trying to show that $P_{ii}=0$ since that is not related to the problem. In general I think you are misunderstanding some definitions and it would make your question more readable (and helpful to yourself) if you post the full definitions of all terms used.

Comment: I think I do not explain clearly. In fact, your sentence"if the Markov chain reached $i$ it could transition to $j$" is right because $P_{ij}>0$. And "it never reaches $i$ again" because $P_{ji}^k=0, \forall k\geq 1$. But why this contradicts with the recurrence of $i$ in the mathematical expression. I know the meaning but how to express it explicitly.